# Extending a object and assigning it to its parent

Tags: typescript

I am not sure if the title sounds correct. Please suggest, if needs revisions.

I have a object called `programme`

```
export class Programme {
    id: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    subject: string;
    level: string;
    tutorId: string;
    click: number;

    constructor(level?: string) {
        this.click = 0;
        this.level = level ? level : "";
    }
}
```

And i have another object `ProgrammeWrapper`

```
export class ProgrammeWrapper extends Programme{
    lesson: Lesson[];
    tutor: User;

    constructor(prog: Programme){
        super();
    }
}
```

And now this is where the issue arise:

```
var programme = new Programme();//this is coming from database
var user = new User();
var lessons = new Lesson[];
var programmeWrap = new ProgrammeWrapper();
programmeWrap.tutor = user;
programmeWrap.lessons = lessons;
```

How can i assign the programme? to the programmeWrapper?

Comment: I think you don't really understand what inheritance is. Maybe read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is written ProgrammeWrapper is a Programme, there is no need to create a different instance of Programme.

A ProgrammeWrapper is also a Programme, all the properties of Programme are available on ProgrammeWrapper as well.

The ProgrammeWrapper could be written like this:

```js
export class ProgrammeWrapper extends Programme{
        lesson: Lesson[];
        tutor: User;

        constructor(level? : string){
            super(level);
        }
    }
```

And be used like this:

```js
var user = new User();
var lessons = new Lesson[];
var programmeWrap = new ProgrammeWrapper();
programmeWrap.tutor = user;
programmeWrap.lessons = lessons;
programmeWrap.id = '5'; // Programme property is available
```

If all you want is to have an object with that interface and access it you could do this:

```js
interface Programme {
    id: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    subject: string;
    level: string;
    tutorId: string;
    click: number;
}

class ProgrammeWrapper {
    lesson: string[];
    tutor: string;
    constructor(public prog: Programme) {
    }
}

let programme: Programme = null; // comes from somewhere else
let programmeWrapper = new ProgrammeWrapper(programme);

console.log(programmeWrapper.prog.id);
```

Comment: Thanks @toskv However I have programme coming from database, how can i put it in the ProgrammeWrapper?

Comment: that depends, does Programme have any behavior? Methods? Or is it just a plain object?

Comment: if it's a plain object easiest solution would be to just have Programme as an interface and ProgrammeWrapper to have it as a class property.

Comment: no, you can't since there's no casting in typescript, only type assertion. I'll add an example in a minute.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing, I am getting a type error even if i have initialised.

Comment: Should the ProgrammeWrapper implements Programme

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks.