# Object says array size is 0 but it has 6 elements inside

Tags: typescript

I have a `ProgrammeWrapper` but i an array inside. So when i trying to console the wrapper, the below is the behaviour what i am seeing.

[image]

When i reading the lesson on the programme, it says empty array. Any lead will be good. Here is the [object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802854/7683108) i am using

Comment: Is it possible that the `lesson` array was not initialized at the time of your `console.log`?

Comment: @Raven nope. I just checked the programmeWrapper is initialised. and lesson and user both object is initialised.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that the first line is generated when the log is written but the next lines are generated when you expand the log. Run this code in the console:

```
test = {lesson: [1, 2, 3]}; setTimeout(() => test.lesson.push(4), 0); test
```

What this means is that the array changes after the log is written and so the first line isn't updated with the new size.

Furthermore, every time you expand a line in the log, all the inner values are evaluated and remain constant too, even if further changes are made. You can actually get to the following situation:

```
Object {lesson: Array(3)}
    lesson:Array(4)
        0: 1
        1: 2
        2: 3
        3: 4
        4: 5
        length: 5
    __proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: I am using @Angular4 and Typescript and that behaviour is seen while using pipe. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the pipe output?

Comment: it basically filters lessons and returns programme wrapper with on going classes. Lessons has dates, if the date falls after today than i display. if not don't display.

Comment: And what is the problem you experience? Some lessons don't appear even though they are there and fit the filter?

Comment: not some all lessons are empty when it comes to filter. thus, i am unable to filter.

Comment: Give me a sec. I will share a image.

Comment: At ngOnInit of the component i am using the pipe.

Comment: At ngOnInit of the component i am loading the ProgrammeWrapper[] and the same component i am using pipe.

Comment: Sure. `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" *ngFor="let programme of programmes | search: searchText"></div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147930/discussion-between-user1911-and-shai).